# Picking value from two xml files in xsl1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two XML files, Input1 and Input2. I have to generate sum in the Output but picking value from both the Inputs.

For example -

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//INVOICE/DOC/EINV[document('input2.xml')/Codes/Description[@code=../ABC][@type = '2']]/BET)"/>
```

The path in this statement is for Input1.xml. In between, it is checking the document Input2.xml, @type will always be '2', @code(@ in input2.xml) value will be /abc(element of input1.xml) elements value.

Input1.xml -

```
INVOICE
 DOC
  EINV
   ABC
   BET
  EINV
 DOC
INVOICE
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Also, it would be helpful to have both `Input1.xml` and `Input2.xml` and the expected output included as well-formed XML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one:

```
  <xsl:param name="file1" select="//INVOICE/DOC/EINV/BET"/>
  <xsl:param name="file2" select="document('input2.xml')/Codes/Description[@code=../ABC][@type = '2']/BET"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="sum($file1,$file2)"/>
```